python multiprocessing equivalent for lots of bash ampersands and redirects?
I've got a script where the functionality I need has outgrown bash (or at least outgrown my desire to maintain it in bash) so I'm looking at how to do this in python instead.
I've looked through the multiprocessing documentation to my ability to understand it, and I'm still not entirely sure which combination of map-ping, starmap-ping, async-ing, and other python magic I need to use. The starting point for this block would be represented in bash like this:
command1 argument1a arg1b > output1 < /dev/null &
command2 argument2a arg2b > output2 < /dev/null &
command3 argument3a arg3b > output3 < /dev/null &
wait
do_something_else

building out the command and argument list is easy enough, I'm having trouble with the job control equivalents and getting the script to wait in the right places.
Some relevant things I'm trying to accomplish:

each command may be different or another instance of the same command, but each is associated with a unique output file so I don't have to worry about locking/overwriting.
none of the processes need to take any input.
stderr should be printed to the terminal, although if for some reason it's way easier to put it into a separate file that would be fine as well.
I want all of the processes to start more or less simultaneously (the precise order/timing is not important here)


This is actually pretty easy—at least if you don’t need it to be async.  Perhaps show the code you’ve tried?

you are kinda looking in to the wrong module, you should be using the subprocess module instead, specifically Popen.

What's the narrow, specific technical problem that you got hung up on while trying to do this yourself?

(in general, it should look something like p1 = subprocess.Popen(['command1', 'argument1a', 'arg1b'], stdout=open('output1', 'w'), stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL); p2 = ...; p3 = ...; p1.wait(); p2.wait(); p3.wait(); subprocess.call(['do_something_else']))

Just call then with subprocess.Popen - passing open, writable, files as the stdin argument. No need to change the defaults for stderr or stdin will work as you want. The Popen call will start them in the background.
Afterwards, you can call the .poll() method on the Popen wrapper objects: if it returns None while the process is still running, or its exit code as an integer. You may call .wait() instead of poll, and that will block your main process until that child is finished.
import subprocess
import time

list_of_programs_args_and_outputs = [
   (["command1", "arg1a", "arg1b"], output1),
   ...
]

def myfunc():
     procs = []
     for args, filename in list_of_programs_and_outputs:
         procs.append(subprocess.Popen(*args, stdout=open(filename, "wt")))
     not_done = []; done = []
     while procs:
         for proc in procs:
              if (result:=proc.poll()) is not None:
                   done.append(proc)
              else:
                  not_done.append(proc)
         procs = not_done
         # do Python stuff: print progress, sleep, etc...
         time.sleep(0.01) # if you are doing nothing in the Python code while waiting, better put some sleep here, otherwise the Python runtime will use 100% of a CPU core doing nothing.
    ...
                  



This works, though the poll() approach it's demonstrating is only called for if there actually is "Python stuff" the OP wants to do while waiting for the processes -- which isn't the case for the stated shell script they want to convert -- and introduces the risk of spending a full CPU core doing a busy-wait if no sleep is added to that loop.

Indeed - I've added an explicit sleep clause there. I underestimate people's habits of copying and pasting directly from these answers.

since you are not manually parsing either stdout or stderr i would just pass shell=True to subprocess.Popen and let the shell do all the piping. be sure to read the Security Concerns of shell=True (don't use it in a web server)
from subprocess import Popen


proc_text =["echo hello", "echo world", "echo idk > val.txt"]

processes = []
for text in proc_text:
    proc = Popen(text,shell=True)
    processes.append(proc)

for proc in processes:
    proc.communicate()
    if proc.returncode:
        raise RuntimeError(f"process '{proc.args}' returned {proc.returncode}")

if you don't need the shell to expand your command (command1 is an executable, and args don't need expansion), you can save the cost of spawning a shell to parse the command by using shell=False as follows.
Popen(['command1', 'argument1a', 'arg1b'], 
      stdout=open('output1', 'w'), stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)

you can use stderr=sys.stderr if you want the children to follow the same stderr as the python script in case the user wants to dump it to a file instead of displaying it in the terminal.

Boo, hiss re: shell=True. Adding a shell to the mix reduces portability (commands need to be written specifically for Windows or UNIX -- f/e, /dev/null as used in the OP's code isn't portable between those platforms), adds room for security issues that wouldn't exist otherwise (f/e shell injection attacks if anything is parameterized), makes error handling worse (you no longer get different exceptions based on exactly how the subprocess's startup failed) and makes everything a bit slower.

(and "the terminal" doesn't do any piping at all; it's the shell that does redirection, not the terminal)

@CharlesDuffy yeh, but that's what the docs specifically mention If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want convenient access to other shell features which somewhat matches what he is asking.

The only shell feature used here (other than parsing the command into words) is redirection -- >output1 and </dev/null. Since those are trivially replaced with stdout=open('output1', 'w') and stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, what's the point? I'd understand a little more if process substitution or complex pipelines were in use, but that's not the case at hand; there are no "other shell features" in use that subprocess doesn't provide a convenient alternative to.

@CharlesDuffy maybe command1 is itself a shell script or an alias or the parameters are another command which needs expansion (which i have ran into very frequently), it is just a lot more convenient for automating build scripts and such, this is if security is not a concern (and it rarely is for this kind of scripts).

Doesn't make any difference if it's a shell script -- it's running in a subprocess, so you pay a separate cost for that child shell invoked to run the script whether or not you paid for a parent shell (this is desirable behavior: for it to be otherwise shebangs couldn't be honored so scripts would behave differently depending on what shell you started them from). And noninteractive shells don't read dotfiles so they wouldn't know what aliases the user has defined in the first place, if aliases were enabled by default in noninteractive shells at all, which in bash they're not.

(bash does support exported functions in noninteractive shells, but even then that won't work reliably with the code in this answer, because subprocess.Popen uses /bin/sh rather than bash by default).
